# Calculating output of a solar cell

Tags: estimation, solar-cells, efficient-energy-use

If we are given a particular solar panel with some semiconductor tabs in it,
How can I calculate the output of the Solar panel per metre square 
With the values of ( average hours of sun everyday, efficiency, angle of solar panel) [image]

Answer (score 0):

The standard value for solar radiation at the surface is called "AM1" and it's 1 kW/m^2. In the example you post, the efficiency of the cell is 30.7%, so if it was a meter square it would produce 307 watts under test conditions.

It is not a meter, however. So simply think about stacking these together to form a panel of any size you wish. Most cells today are 6-inches on a side, but I'm not sure about the Spectrolab ones because they're an entirely different technology.

Simply tile them out, estimate the amount of area that's not covered due to gaps between the cells and the clipped corners, divide by the area, multiply by 30.7, and then take off a couple of percent for wiring and isolation diodes.

That's the perfect output, or "nameplate rating". The rest is entirely based on your location and installation. To calculate that you need to use a calculator like [this one](https://pvwatts.nrel.gov).